# Automatically rebase Git sub-branches

Tags: git, version-control, branch, rebase

Say I have a git history like this:

```
A--B--C--D <master>
   \--E--F <topic1>
         \--G <topic2>
```

That is, I have two topic branches, where one feature depends upon another. In the meantime, work has been done on `master`, so I want to rebase `topic1`. This results in:

```
A--B--C--D <master>
   |     \--E'--F' <topic1>
   \--E--F--G <topic2>
```

That is, `topic1` was rebased but `topic2` was not. I want to get to this:

```
A--B--C--D <master>
         \--E'--F' <topic1>
                \--G <topic2>
```

But if I simply do `git rebase topic1 topic2`, Git will try to replay commits `E` and `F` on top of `E'` and `F'`, which will fail because they edit the same lines of the same files. So I have to run something unwieldy like this:

```
git rebase --onto topic1 <sha1-of-commit-F> topic2
```

... which requires doing a `git log` and copy-pasting something (using the *mouse* like some sort of *loser*!). I know this isn't exactly heartbreaking, but this usage pattern must be fairly common for Git. Can anyone think of a way to rebase `topic1` and `topic2` in one fell swoop?

Comment: According to the rebase man page, `Note that any commits in HEAD which introduce the same textual changes as a commit in HEAD..<upstream> are omitted (i.e., a patch already accepted upstream with a different commit message or timestamp will be skipped).` your proposed command should work fine.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't realise that. I may be confused about what's causing my rebases to fail. I'll investigated and come back to this question. Thanks

Comment: you might get conflicts when your `E'` or `F'` were merged with conflicts as the diff will change.

Comment: OK, I've realised that the reason this is happening (rather obviously, it now seems), is when I modify `E'` so it no longer introduces the same changes as `E`. It doesn't happen for every commit. The solutions seems to be to just use `git rebase --skip` in those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Nils_M` pointed out in a comment, the rebase man page says `Note that any commits in HEAD which introduce the same textual changes as a commit in HEAD..<upstream> are omitted (i.e., a patch already accepted upstream with a different commit message or timestamp will be skipped).`

The only reason Git would replay `E` and `F` during the rebase of `topic2` onto `topic1` is if `E'` or `F'` has been modified from their originals. In that case, when the rebase stops due the merge conflict, simply use `git rebase --skip`.

Answer (score 3):

Git 2.38 now has the `--update-refs` arg for `rebase`.