# Git rebase and automatically update branch pointer?

Tags: git, branch, rebase, feature-branch

I have a set of branches like the following:

```
            * 444ddd - somefeature3
           /
          * 333ccc - somefeature2
         /
        * 222bbb - somefeature1
       /
------* 111aaa - master
```

If I were on a single branch (let's say `somefeature3` without `somefeature2` or `somefeature1` existing), I could update all of my commits by doing `git rebase -i 111aaa`. In other words, I could go from this:

```
            * 444ddd - somefeature3
           /
          * 333ccc
         /
        * 222bbb
       /
------* 111aaa - master
```

...to this:

```
            * 444eee - somefeature3
           /
          * 333ddd
         /
        * 222ccc
       /
------* 111aaa - master
```

In particular, commit `222bbb` was replaced with `222ccc`, `333ccc` was replaced with `333ddd`, and `444ddd` was replaced with `444eee`.

However, if I care about the branch pointers `somefeature2` and `somefeature1`, they won't get updated in this scenario. I would go from this:

```
            * 444ddd - somefeature3
           /
          * 333ccc - somefeature2
         /
        * 222bbb - somefeature1
       /
------* 111aaa - master
```

...to this:

```
            * 444eee - somefeature3
           /
          * 333ddd        * 333ccc - somefeature2
         /               /
        * 222ccc        * 222bbb - somefeature1
       /               /
------* --------------*
       111aaa - master
```

What I want to have happen instead is for the final state to look like this, with the branch pointers `somefeature2` and `somefeature1` updated along with `somefeature3`:

```
            * 444eee - somefeature3
           /
          * 333ddd - somefeature2
         /
        * 222ccc - somefeature1
       /
------* 111aaa - master
```

Is there any way to have Git automatically update the branch pointers for `somefeature1` and `somefeature2` as well as part of the `git rebase -i`, producing this end state?

(meta: this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652293/automatically-rebase-git-sub-branches), but it goes further by asking if it's possible to have Git do the appropriate foo automatically)

Comment: Please show us the branch structure you want after your rebase operation.

Comment: Edited my question to include more diagrams and detail.

Comment: Git really needs a "multi-branch" rebase command, aimed at these kinds of situations. Now that `git rebase -r` exists, the internal rebase code has enough machinery to achieve the correct result; it just needs some *external* way to specify the right set of names to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Closest I can get to easy is to use interactive rebase and add in `exec git branch -f branchname` after the picks for those tips.  If this turns in to a regular thing for you, you're in scripting territory, use your favorite editor to run `git for-each-ref --points-at` on each line with a format that spits the updates.